# UiAutomator cannot find UiObject that on a screen

Tags: automated-tests, android-uiautomator, ui-testing

I trying to click on a button with UiAutomator, but receive error `"androidx.test.uiautomator.UiObjectNotFoundException"`

I tried to locate object in two ways.

1. `UiObject cartButton = uiDevice.findObject(new Selector().resourceId("R.id.group_cart_add_button"));`
2. `UiObject2 cartButton = uiDevice.findObject(By.res(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext().getPackageName(), "R.id.group_cart_add_button"));`

Then I use `cartButton.click()` but both times I receive an error.

In hierarchy this object is exist [image]

And when I try to find it in Evaluate tool, I can do it:[image]

But if I try to click, I receive an error:[image]

Why?

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue. Any info? Any update on this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
String packageName = "your-app-package-name"
String fullCartButtonResourceId = packageName + ":id/group_cart_add_button";
UiObject2 cartButton = mDevice.findObject(By.res(uk));
```

or

```
UiObject cartButton = findObject(new UiObject(new UiSelector().resourceId(fullCartButtonResourceId));
```